# How do i print logs in IST timezone using env_logger crate in Rust?

Tags: rust

The following minimal example. Below code print logs in the UTC timezone. How do I print logs in the IST timezone?

```
use std::env;
if env::var("RUST_LOG").is_err() {
    env::set_var("RUST_LOG", "proxy=debug,common=debug");
}

env_logger::Builder::from_default_env()
    .default_format_timestamp_nanos(true)
    .init();
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm afraid that it can't be done. Under the hood, `env_logger` uses [`humantime` crate](https://crates.io/crates/humantime) to format various timestamps. For example, you enable nano-second precision so the implementation is delegated to [`humantime::format_rfc3339_nanos`](https://docs.rs/humantime/2.0.0/humantime/fn.format_rfc3339_nanos.html). Its documentation reads:

> The value is always UTC and ignores system timezone.

Answer (score 1):

If someone else is looking for this, its actually possible:

```rust
use chrono::Utc;
use env_logger::Builder;
use log::LevelFilter;
use std::io::Write;

fn main() {
    Builder::new()
        .format(|buf, record| {
            let dt = Utc::now(); // Current time in UTC

             // Convert to Indian Standard Time (UTC+05:30)
            let ist = dt.with_timezone(&chrono::FixedOffset::east_opt(5 * 3600 + 30 * 60).unwrap()); 
           

            writeln!(
                buf,
                "{} [{}] - {}",
                ist.format("%Y-%m-%dT%H:%M:%S"),
                record.level(),
                record.args()
            )
        })
        .filter(None, LevelFilter::Info)
        .init();

    log::warn!("warn");
    log::info!("info");
    log::debug!("debug");
}
```

This will output:

```
2023-08-27T08:27:28 [WARN] - warn
2023-08-27T08:27:28 [INFO] - info
```

Source:
https://rust-lang-nursery.github.io/rust-cookbook/development_tools/debugging/config_log.html#include-timestamp-in-log-messages